# Custom EventSources built using the (string name) base constructor aren't logging

Tags: c#, .net, etw, .net-4.6.2

I'm trying to implement ETW with a custom class based on [EventSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx) (as is the intended design). I'm seeing logs just fine when using the [base constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393385(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class TestSource : EventSource
{
    public static readonly TestSource Log = new TestSource();

    public TestSource() : base() { }

    public void LogMe(string msg)
    {
        WriteEvent(1, msg);
    }
}
```

but when I switch to using the [constructor that lets you define the name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823283(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    public TestSource() : base("TestSource") { }
```

Logs no longer appear.

I'm not having issues in the constructor ([I've used the flag to throw construction errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.constructionexception(v=vs.110).aspx)) or when calling to write out the log ([used the flag for this as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsourcesettings(v=vs.110).aspx)). Further, [IsEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393388(v=vs.110).aspx) is "true" once I've added the source to the Diagnostic Events window in Visual Studio.

Thus, the source registers correctly, and the Write method executes successfully, but the log is never actually sent. Everything appears to be the same as when I use `base()`, but logs won't appear unless I use that constructor. Is there something I'm missing, or is this a bug?

Per sulyman's request for the whole code, this is in a WebApi controller running in a Service Fabric service:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [EventSource(Name = "TestSource")]
    public class TestSource : EventSource
    {
        public static readonly TestSource Log = new TestSource();

        public TestSource() : base()
        {
        }

        public void LogMe(string msg)
        {
            WriteEvent(1, msg);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {

        TestSource.Log.LogMe("Hello!");
        return new string[] {"value1", "value2"};
    }
}
```

(That version works, because it's using the parameterless constructor.)

Comment: please add the whole code you are trying to run

Comment: add [Event] attribute to LogMe

Comment: No change with the EventAttribute added.

Comment: use he Nuget based version, not the inbox version : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource

Comment: Thanks, worth a try. Unfortunately, doesn't appear to have changed anything - if I define the name with an EventSourceAttribute, the EventSource continues to log normally, but if I define it by calling the (string name) constructor, no dice.

Comment: What are you using to view the logs?
I used the 'Diagnostic Events' viewer and I can see the output there for the version passing a parameter into the base constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ensure that your base class' constructor is visible to subclasses.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I'm following your concern - EventSource is part of the framework (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx), not custom code. The constructor is visible and available to subclasses, or it would've been a compile issue instead of a missing logs issue.